# Past perfect or not

Tags: tenses

I have a question about the past perfect.

A mother was charged guilty unless at least one person had witnessed that she **had given** birth or unless the accused could prove that she had made preparations regarding childbirth or for the child itself.

Somebody told me I shouldn´t use it for "had given birth" and use the simple past (gave birth) instead without explaining why but the birth did happen before they might have been found guilty, didn´t it. Therefore I should use the past perfect?

Comment: By *witness*, do you mean *observe* or *testify*? It can mean either. I think the person giving you grammatical advice assumed that it meant *observe*, in which case their criticism is correct.

Comment: It means to testify. This must have happened before a possible trial. In case of it meaning "observe" wouldn't you have to change both verbs:...charged guilty unless at least one person witnessed that she gave birth or....?

Comment: I should explain the context I guess. This is about infanticide. The trial took place if a woman was suspected to have killed her newborn child.  To witness birth (meaning observe) doesn´t make sense in that context since a pregnant woman would not have been brought to trial (if it was physically obvious that she was pregnant). That´s why I was wondering....

Comment: The two alternatives would be _had witnessed her giving birth_ or _witnessed [in court] that she had given birth._ However, the woman would not have been brought to trial unless she was known to have given birth. Didn't the witness have to testify that the child had been stillborn or died of natural causes?

Comment: I am confused right now.  I meant to say that somebody had to witness her giving birth in the past in court. That should be "witnessed" and had given birth" right? How do you come with the first alternative?

Comment: Additionally, authorities wanted to appeal to societies’ moral understandings regarding sexuality. In fact, unwelcomed behavior like pre-marital sex and the consequences of birthing bastard children was considered immoral and thus, to be avoided (62-63). The introduction of the act “An Act to Prevent the Destroying and Murthering of Bastard Children” was intended to contribute to resolving the mentioned concerns. This law primarily targeted unmarried women who had concealed their pregnancy to not inform anybody or ask for help whilst being in labor (21 James I, c. 27).

Comment: This also included the unmarried women whose newborn was either dead or missing (21 James I, c. 27). A mother was charged guilty unless at least one person had witnessed that she had given birth or unless the accused could prove that she had made preparations regarding childbirth or for the child itself (Martin 21).    This is the original context.  Why can´t you say "had witnessed" and "had given birth" if the witness didn´t witness in court?

Comment: @Marcin: Because if you're talking about actually them being present at the birth, they are witnessing the birth *at the same time* as she is giving birth. So the witnessing does not take place earlier, and you should not use the past perfect.

Comment: That sounds like a contrived example, not only because no-one was ever "charged guilty."

Either way is it clear that here "unless the accused…" makes no difference?

How could whether "authorities wanted to appeal to moral understandings regarding sexuality" change the grammar or semantics of the main passage, please?